# Java - SimpleDateFormat parse from String issue

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse the following string to a Date object:

```
String str = "04/15/2014 10:30:24"
```

I'm using `SimpleDateFormat` :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date orderDate = sdf.parse(str);
java.sql.Date orderSqlDate = new java.sql.Date(orderDate.getTime());
```

but `orderSqlDate` always returned: 04/15/2014 00:00:00

how to use `SimpleDateFormat` in java exactly?

Comment: Works fine for me. How are you using `orderDate`?

Comment: yeah it perfectly right ... and working just fine

Comment: ITs working whats prob with that? and SFD use to format date.

Comment: Show us what you do. Where do you see that the hours/minutes/seconds are lost?

Comment: after parse `orderDate`, I will cast it to `java.sql.Date`: `new java.sql.Date(orderDate.getTime())`.

The output of `System.out.print(orderDate.getTime())` is `04/15/2014 00:00:00`

Comment: `orderDate.getTime()` returns a `long` so you wouldn't see that. What is it you are _actually_ doing? Add an edit to your question

Comment: This is my code:
`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
 
java.util.Date orderDate = sdf.parse("04/15/2014 10:30:24");

java.sql.Date orderSqlDate = new java.sql.Date(orderDate.getTime()));`

Comment: Put that in your question. There's an `edit` button right below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`java.sql.Date` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) states

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values
>   wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' **by setting
>   the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero** in the
>   particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

If you're going to use `java.sql.Date`, there's no way around this.

Comment: @hoangkianh You can accept an answer by checking the checkmark next to the score. Do this to indicate you are satisfied with the answer provided.

Comment: @hoangkianh Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

You are also doing correct.

But to get the result in the format you want, you need to use  .format("/your format/") method after parsing the string.

```
String date = "15/12/2014 10:42:24";

SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

Date parseDate = dateParser.parse(date);

formatter.format(parseDate) // this will change format of date as you want.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the way you parse is wrong. Are you sure you print orderDate right ?

The following code demonstrates both parsing and formatting (printing).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date orderDate = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse("04/15/2014 10:30:24");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(orderDate));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Provide Locale in the SimpleDateFormat constructor, otherwise parsing might be dependant on your local settings:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ROOT);
```